# How can we use JQuery in asp.net pages?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

How can we use JQuery in asp.net pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Getting Started with jQuery in Visual Studio 2008

http://blogs.msdn.com/bursteg/archive/2009/06/05/getting-started-with-jquery-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That makes no sense at all , i assume you want to know how to use jQuery in ASP.net , just add a reference to the script and look at some of the tutorials they provide here http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: Ahhh it seems someone finally edited it to make a little more sense :)

Comment: thanks. can I use JQuery in Perl? for example for change date format?

Comment: I am pretty sure you cant since i am not a perl programmer but as far as i know doesnt run in browser , i guess you could use it to out put jQuery code but not to change a date format , i am sure perl has function built in to do that

Answer (score 0):

why you cann't [google](http://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1CHNG_enIN344IN344&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=JQuery+in+asp.net+pages) it :(

Here are some links

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=231

http://www.aspnetpro.com/newsletterarticle/2009/05/asp200905jk_l/asp200905jk_l.asp